# i tried reading a .mat file through scipy.io but the path i copied is displaying error. I don't know what to do

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, dataset

[The error it has been displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emuZ7.png)

I want my file to run and display the datasets

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not embed images of source code, data or errors. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to others as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1):

Your filename includes the characters `\U`. That is an *escape sequence*, and Python expects a Unicode code point to follow it.

Add an `r` in front of the filename, e.g. `loadmat(r'C:\Users\IFE\Desktop\CMP')`, to disable escape sequences in the string.

Of course, you'll also want to assign the return value to a variable, e.g.

```
mat = loadmat(r'C:\Users\IFE\Desktop\CMP')
```